# OpenCV - how to create Mat from uint8_t pointer

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following C++ code:

```
void foo(const uint8_t* data, int height, int width) {
  // need to create a cv::Mat from *data, which is a pointer to grayscale image data

  // doesn't work correctly (compiles, but array access on the mat leads to a segmentation fault)
  auto img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, &data);

  // how can I fix the line above to create a proper cv::Mat?
}

// I'm calling foo like this
// img is a grayscale image
foo(img.ptr<uint8_t>(0), img.cols, img.rows);
```

Could anyone point me on what's wrong with my syntax on creating the matrix inside of foo?

Comment: remove the "&", your data already is a pointer..

Comment: and in the last row swap cols and rows, your function is ordered height, width

Comment: fof non-continuous matrices you have to add the stepsize to both, function header and mat constructor. but since your question is "mat from pointet" I guess it should be continuous...

Comment: thanks Micka!  removing the & and casting the uint8_t pointer to a void pointer fixed it.  Brand new to c++ and pointers.  Appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 11):

On this page [cv::Mat Class Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) , we can find the cv::Mat construction function as follows:

```
///! 2017.10.05 09:31:00 CST
/// cv::Mat public construction

Mat ()
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type)
Mat (Size size, int type)
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, const Scalar &s)
Mat (Size size, int type, const Scalar &s)
Mat (int ndims, const int *sizes, int type)
Mat (int ndims, const int *sizes, int type, const Scalar &s)
Mat (const Mat &m)
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
Mat (Size size, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
Mat (int ndims, const int *sizes, int type, void *data, const size_t *steps=0)
Mat (const Mat &m, const Range &rowRange, const Range &colRange=Range::all())
Mat (const Mat &m, const Rect &roi)
Mat (const Mat &m, const Range *ranges)
```

---

To  create `cv::Mat` from `uint8_t pointer`, we can use those two functions:

```
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
Mat (Size size, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

---

Here is my experiment:

```
///! 2017.10.05 09:40:33 CST
/// convert uint8_t array/pointer to cv::Mat

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(){        
    uint8_t uarr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 2;
    cv::Size sz(cols,rows);

    cv::Mat mat1(sz,CV_8UC3, uarr);
    cv::Mat mat2(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, uarr);

    std::cout<< "mat1: \n"<<mat1 << "\n\nmat2:\n" << mat2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

The result is excepted:

```
mat1: 
[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6;
   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12]

mat2:
[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6;
   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12]
```

Comment: A more general way: [How to create cv::Mat from buffer (array of T* data) using a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207847/how-to-create-cvmat-from-buffer-array-of-t-data-using-a-template-function/48207940#48207940)

Comment: how about unknow size?