# How to initialize a Mat with three channels

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to initialize a kernel of three channels in `OpenCV 2.4`, and I looked at the documentation where there is no example of how to do it for `Mat`s of more than one channel.

```
float data_[12] = {111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123,
                   211, 212, 213, 221, 222, 223};
cv::Mat kernel(2, 2, CV_32FC3);
// How to initialize kernel with data_?
```

Is there any way of initializing above `kernel` with `data_`?

Answer (score 1):

```
///! 2017.10.05 09:40:33 CST
/// convert uint8_t array/pointer to cv::Mat

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(){        
    uint8_t uarr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 2;
    cv::Size sz(cols,rows);

    cv::Mat mat1(sz,CV_8UC3, uarr);
    cv::Mat mat2(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, uarr);

    std::cout<< "mat1: \n"<<mat1 << "\n\nmat2:\n" << mat2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is excepted:

```
mat1: 
[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6;
   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12]

mat2:
[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6;
   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12]
```

Details to my another answer:
[OpenCV - how to create Mat from uint8_t pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579398/opencv-how-to-create-mat-from-uint8-t-pointer/46576614#46576614)