# Creating Your Own Linear Filter

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am new to Opencv C++. I am trying to convolve a mask with an image. For this I want to create my own mask so that I can use the filter2D array function to convolve my mask with the image. The mask which I want to create is:

```
char mask [3][3]=  {{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1}};
```

For this I have tried the code below(to generate this mask):-

```
Mat kernel(3,3, CV_8UC1, Scalar(-1,0,1));
```

i have printed the mask values as

```
std::cout << kernel;
```

but the answer which I am getting is 
      0,   0,   0;
      0,   0,   0;
      0,   0,   0

I am expecting the answer to be 
   -1,   0,   1;
   -1,   0,   1;
   -1,   0,   1

I know I am making a mistake in writing the channels properly. Can anyone help me understand what does the channel(CV_8UC1.... ) means and how to correct it and get the proper output.

Comment: Mat kernel(3,3, CV_8UC1, Scalar(-1,0,1));  means, that you set first channel to -1, second channel to 0, third channel to 1. But since you only have a single channel matrix, only the first channel is used: -1. But since you have unsigned type, it will be saturated to 0. So each pixel of your sample image is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CV_8UC1 means 1 channel, 8 bit, uchar image.

Scalar is used to set the value of each channel, not each pixel/coordinate.

**Ex 1:**

```
Mat kernel(3,3, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0))
```

would mean creating a 3X3 matrix with 0s and since it is of type **CV_8UC1**, you can mention only one value, in this case 0.

**EX 2:**

```
Mat kernel(3,3, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255))
```

means creating a 3X3 matrix with 3 channels since the type is **CV_8UC3** and setting channel 1 to 0, channel 2 to 0, channel 3 to 255.

Hence for your purpose to set row values, you cannot use scalar. 
Instead do this:

```
Mat C = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1);
```

Check [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html) for more information.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a `kernel` with `negative` element for `filter2D`, then you should't use the data type of `CV_8UC1`. `There is no negative value in unsigned type`.

And `Mat kernel(3,3, CV_8UC1, Scalar(-1,0,1));` means create a signal- channel-unsigned-char kernel. You set `Scalar(-1,0,1)` to `kernel`, then only `the first element(that is double -1)` is used,  while `saturate_cast<unchar>(-1) = 0`.

Generally, use `CV_32FC1` instead.

---

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    float mask[9] = {-1,0,1, -1, 0, 1, -1,0,1};
    Mat kernel(3,3, CV_32FC1);
    memcpy(kernel.data, mask, sizeof(float)*9);
    cout << kernel<<endl;
}
```

---

The result:

```
[-1, 0, 1;
 -1, 0, 1;
 -1, 0, 1]
```

---

A similar question:

[How to create cv::Mat from buffer (array of T* data) using a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207847/how-to-create-cvmat-from-buffer-array-of-t-data-using-a-template-function/48207940#48207940)