# OpenCV Mat from unsigned short array

Tags: c++, opencv

I have unsigned short array of size 6400 which correspond to a 80*80 16bit 1 channel image that I would like to display with OpenCV.

I created a CV_16UC1 Mat but I have no idea how to set its data from the orignal unsigned short array.

```
img_data = new unsigned short[80*80];
/* some code that set the unsigned short array elements */

cv::Mat img(80, 80, CV_16UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

img.data = ??? ; // conversion from unsigned short * to uchar *   ????
```

Comment: you may use [std::memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a

Comment: @DanMašek exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48207940/3547485

Comment: @Silencer very intersting solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the mat [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) that takes a user allocated buffer indicating the type as CV_16UC1.

```
cv::Mat img(80, 80, CV_16UC1, img_data);
```

Comment: The data is already in unsigned short... it should be CV_16UC1 in the first line and it is not needed to be converted. otherwise it will interpret the data as uchar and then it will have different data. One thing to add to your answer would be that the data is not copied, and it must be deallocated after use.