# efficient way to create an opencv mat from std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, copy

If I want to create an opencv mat from a std::vector I use the following function:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)

vector<double> myData;
cv::Mat m(100, 100, 1, myData.data(), myData.size())
```

This constructor does not copy the data, so when the vector is temp and we return the mat, mat has invalid data so I return a clone of it which is inefficient.

```
void doProcessing()
{
  //...
  Mat m = getMat(12.2, 144, ...);
  cout<< m.at<double>(0,0);
  //...
}

Mat getMat(some parameters){
  vector<double> myData;
  //do some processing on parameters and myData
  cv::Mat m(100, 100, 1, myData.data(), myData.size());
  return m.clone();
}
```

is there any better way? how can I use std::move to only move the pointer?
I don't want to copy the data, just moving vector data pointer in O(1).

Comment: You *must* keep the vector for as long as you use the `Mat` because the vector is the only thing holding the data. What about creating a structure containing both the vector and the `cv::Mat` (it would be *movable*)?

Comment: Can you provide code illustrating your *actual* problem so we can suggest solutions?

Comment: is the size of your vector known and fixed during the computation stuff?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207847/how-to-create-cvmat-from-buffer-array-of-t-data-using-a-template-function/48207940#48207940

Comment: @Micka, no the size is dynamic.

Comment: @Silencer, in link you provided the data is copied, I don't want to copy the data.

Comment: If you don't want to copy, then keep the vector as long as the mat lives.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refactor so as `getMat` returns a vector, and convert vector to `cv::Mat` later in `doProcessing()`:

```
void doProcessing()
{
  //...
  vector<double> v = getMat(12.2, 144, ...);

  cv::Mat m(100, 100, 1, myData.data(), myData.size());
  cout<< m.at<double>(0,0);
  //...
}

vector<double> getMat(some parameters){
  vector<double> myData;
  //do some processing on parameters and myData

  return myData;
}
```

Comment: Bad method. You return `vector<double>`, at least in C++03, it surely copy the date, but this is not a good idea. And in `doProcessing()`, you still share the memory.