# uchar* to std::vector<uchar> and back?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some image data as a `uchar*`. I need to run processing on it as a `std::vector<uchar>`, and then convert it back. I am using this code:

```
unsigned char* buffer = inputImg.data; //Image data from cv::Mat

    std::vector<uchar> vec;
    size_t size_of_buffer = sizeof(buffer);
    vec.assign(buffer, buffer + size_of_buffer);

    uchar* _compressed = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(vec.data());
```

When I then view the result with:

```
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(_height, _width, inputImg.type(), _compressed );
```

this results in a black image. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:

based on comments below, i have changed the code to:

```
//from Mat
    int COLOR_COMPONENTS = inputImg.channels();
    int _width = inputImg.cols;
    int _height = inputImg.rows;

    //to std::vector and back
    std::vector<uchar> vec;
    size_t size_of_buffer = _width * _height*COLOR_COMPONENTS;

    vec.assign(buffer, buffer + size_of_buffer);
    uchar* _compressed = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(vec.data());
```

As in the answer below, this works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you keep the Data in a cv::Mat? OpenCV has tons of efficient and convenient functions working on Matrices directly.

Comment: I am using TurboJpeg to compress the data to send over tcp. Then unpacking at the other end. My tcp send uses serialisation, which wont take a uchar*

Comment: You will also need attributes named `inputImg.width`, `inputImg.height`, `inputImg.channels`. Using these attributes only you can know the size of buffer as `width * height * channels`

Comment: Thank you! i have edited my question. Using this I still get a black image.

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` seems unnecessary. Why did you add it? If you were getting some sort of error then you might have a typo somewhere in your code or you didn't post the exact code.

Comment: if you imshow inputImg is it black too? (before and/or after your computations)

Comment: for me your code works... probably, either you have a problem in displaying your image, or you are doing something with the data.

Comment: Note that the final pointer _compressed is only valid while the vector vec is in scope.

Comment: Ah, i had made a mistake in my code further down, in the compression. This code works, as in the accepted answer. thank you.

Comment: Why not try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207847/how-to-create-cvmat-from-buffer-array-of-t-data-using-a-template-function/48207940#48207940

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast<uchar*>` on the last line is not needed since `vector<uchar>::data()` is already of type `uchar*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me and displays the image correctly:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png");
    cv::Mat inputImg = input;

    int COLOR_COMPONENTS = inputImg.channels();
    int _width = inputImg.cols;
    int _height = inputImg.rows;

    //to std::vector and back
    std::vector<uchar> vec;
    size_t size_of_buffer = _width * _height*COLOR_COMPONENTS;

    unsigned char* buffer = inputImg.data;

    vec.assign(buffer, buffer + size_of_buffer);
    uchar* _compressed = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(vec.data());

    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(_height, _width, inputImg.type(), _compressed);

    cv::imshow("output", mat);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2013 with OpenCV 3.4

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(buffer)` yields the size of the pointer to the buffer, not the amount of data inside the buffer. You must get the buffer size from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a trick to getting the size of a `uchar*`?

Comment: There is no trick, you need to store the size. You need to know it. In this case, cv::Mat stores it (I think .total() gives you the total amount of elements).

Comment: You are looking for the size of your specific buffer. `uchar*` is a general type, so this will not help you. 
`cv::Mat` has other members that may provide what you need, e.g., `datastart`, `dataend`, `datalimit`.
Side remark: In general, your approach to getting data from the cv::Mat may run into issues like OpenCV adding padding to the individual rows.