# Get C++ OpenCV Mat type from Emgu::CV::Mat

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, emgucv

Is there a an easy conversion function from an Emgu::CV::CVEnum::DepthType and NumberOfChannels to an ordinary C/C++ CVEnum (e.g. CV_8UC3).

Currently I'm having to do the following:

```
if (mat->Depth == Emgu::CV::CvEnum::DepthType::Cv8U && mat->NumberOfChannels == 3)
    return CV_8UC3;
else if (mat->Depth == Emgu::CV::CvEnum::DepthType::Cv8U && mat->NumberOfChannels == 1)
    return CV_8UC1;
else
    throw std::runtime_error("Unknown Image Type");
```

I throw the exception as I don't currently want to have to type out every combination imaginable, but I would still like to have something a bit more robust. Any ideas?

Comment: You could calculate it same way it's calculated in OpenCV (the [`CV_MAKETYPE`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html#gab2ebca36079fd923483abee99d7ff40d) macro.) You already have depth (the enumeration in Emgu has the same values as the corresponding OpenCV symbols) and number of channels.

Comment: And here is a C++ example: [How to create cv::Mat from buffer (array of T* data) using a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207847/how-to-create-cvmat-from-buffer-array-of-t-data-using-a-template-function/48207940#48207940)

Comment: The alternative may be grabbing the pointer to the unmanaged object (which I guess is the underlying `cv::Mat`) and fetching it from that directly.