# Displaying a list of RGB values as a picture FAST in python

Tags: python-3.x, image

I am in need for a way to display a 1d or 2d list of tuples containing values for red, green and blue in a fast way. Like 60fps. The picture will be about 500x500 px and would change slightly every frame. I am not looking for something like:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(THE_IMAGE_LIST, dtype=np.uint8))
img.show()
```

I have tried using the console, but console buffering is difficult at best with python.

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, but I'd recommend using Pygame or Pygame Zero

Comment: You need some kind of GUI framework which is way out of scope for a StackOverflow question.  You may find in the end that Python is the wrong choice of language for this task.

Comment: This is pretty fast... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60787990/2836621

Answer (score 0):

For now I'll use the console with ASCII for gray-scale Images. If anyone in the future knows any better way, feel free to still answer. I wanted something low level. For me pygame and it's friends are to cluttered and I didn't write them my self...